# Post is being deleted when I delete Comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, associations

When I delete my comments, my posts are deleted as well here is my MVC:

Views (in _comments.html.erb)

```
 <%= div_for(comment) do %>
    <div class="comments_wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <p class="lead"><%= comment.body %></p>
            <p><small>Submitted <strong><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</strong> by <%= comment.user.email %></small></p>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <% if comment.user == current_user -%>
                <%= link_to 'Destroy', @comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-default" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end
```

Controller

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

   respond_to do |format|
     if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
     else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
    @comment = @post.comments.find params[:id]
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

Routes

```
resources :post do
   resources :comments
end
```

When I delete a comment I even get a flash notice:

> your post has been deleted

which resides in the post controller...

Comment: In your views you are using both `comment` and `@comment`. Where is `@comment` defined? It must be pointing to a `Post` instance

Comment: can you show us your controller code?

Comment: It sounds like your delete button might be hitting the wrong controller, what route does your server output when you hit delete comment?

Comment: Maybe  you are passing the wrong parameter in the link. It would help if you posted your routes.rb file, but what happens if you pass both the @comment and the @post in the link, like this:
` <% link_to 'Destroy', [@post, @comment], method: :delete %>` ? And then change your destroy method accordingly.

Comment: You should take a closer look at the @comment variable, make sure it's a comment.  This line `link_to 'Destroy', @comment` should probably be `link_to 'Destroy', comment`

Comment: The view code belongs to which view file? And also please post complete code of the view file.

Comment: The code belongs to a _comments partial